# displaying in the form from database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server-2005, ado.net

iam using asp.net and c#. I executed some database operations for displaying data in the form but i got some blank screen alone.If i click the button the values from the database have to be entered in the form without using gridview or datagridview.. but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string connString = "server=Si\\SQLEXPRESS2005;database=rags;Integrated Security=SSPI";
  string sql = @"select * from time";
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

  try
  {
     conn.Open();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();    
     da.Fill(ds, "time");
     DataTable dt = ds.Tables["time"];
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
           Console.WriteLine(row[col]);
        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(20, '='));
     }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
     Console.ReadLine();
  }
  finally
  {
     conn.Close();
  }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, please use `Response.Write()` instead of `Console`.

Comment: As long as the table has the data and your query is correct, you should see something printed on screen. Debug it and see if you get any rows in the DT...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `System.Console` in ASP.NET application.

Do next:

Markup:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="table" />
```

Code:

```
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
    var tableRow = new TableRow();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
       var tableCell = new TableCell();
       tableCell.Text = row[col];
       tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
    }
    table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
 }
```

---

Anyway, your database access code should look like this:

```
try
{
    string connString = ...
    string sql = ...

    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) // not DataSet if you a single database table
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(table);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            // do stuff
        }    
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

i.e.

> Everything wat implements IDisposable, should be disposed.

Comment: hi i got the error in da.fill(table) as;The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments  another error as  Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: @jeni: use different names for HTML table and DATA table.